# ¿Cómo crear similar un select option con otras etiquetas - CSS3?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

A pesar de haber salido una nueva versión de CSS a CSS3 aún no esta definido para cambiar el aspecto de algunas cosas y si existe. Existe el problema de compatibilidad entre algunos navegadores.

El uso de librería es una buena alternativa pero para un diseño donde se requiere velocidad y mejor rendimiento no es la mejor opción más aún cuando estas librerías tienen a cargar estilos css innecesarios y de que hablar del extenso script de los js, al desear agregar cosas atractivas aún sitio y depender de las librerías eso implicaría tener que utilizar una librería por cada cosa nueva que se desea agregar.

Existe otras alternativas como similar el diseño de un `select option` para así darle un diseño más atractivo al diseño que tiene por defecto.

Lo que deseo lograr de este disfraz es que tenga las mismas funciones de un `select option` normal... Es decir, que se oculte al dar clic en otra parte, que si existe una gran cantidad de opciones no se muestre todo, que muestre una barra `scrollbar` tal como lo hace un `select option` normal.

https://jsfiddle.net/aht3nr4u/

Para el disfraz mediante otras etiquetas tengo lo siguiente funcionando:

```js
$("body").on("click", ".selected", function() {
  $(this).next(".options").toggleClass("open");
});

$("body").on("click", ".option", function() {
  var value = $(this).find("span").html();
  $(".selected").html(value);
  $("#sel").val(value);
  $(".options").toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 25%;
}

.selected {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  min-width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.selected:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d7";
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
}

.options {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.options.open {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.search {
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

li>img {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="sel">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="selected">Select an option</div>
    <ul class="options"  id="fbody">
      <input type="text" id="search">
      <li class="option"><span>Option 1</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 2</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 3</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 4</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 5</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 6</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 7</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 8</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 9</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 10</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 11</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 12</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 13</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 14</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 15</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 16</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 17</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 18</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 19</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 20</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 21</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 22</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 23</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 24</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 25</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 26</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 27</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 28</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 29</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 30</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 31</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 32</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>A</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>B</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>C</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>D</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>E</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>H</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>E</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>E</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>A</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Other</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

La cual cumple con las siguientes condiciones:

- Al dar clic, me muestra el listado de las opciones.
- Al seleccionar una opción se añade de la misma forma como si fuera un `select option` y a la vez se agregar el mismo valor en un campo `input` oculto.

Mi idea al final es lograr obtener es tener el siguiente diseño

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La barra del `scrollbar` la podría editar añadiendo este estilo de [demostración jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umjmW/1/).

Tengo casi todo funcionando, solo faltaría agregar esos pequeños detalles que mediante por estilos CSS3 se pueden lograr pero no he logrado darle el mejor estilo :(

He encontrado estos ejemplos de estilos css en [codepen](https://codepen.io/zgreen/pen/dGEin) y en (jsfiddle)[http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/a6NJk/2/]

Pero no he logrado hacer mucho a pesar de los ejemplos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo el inicio de el look que quieres:

```js
$("body").on("click", ".selected", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).siblings(".container-options").toggleClass("open");  
});

$("body").on("click", ".search", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); 
});

$("body").on("click", function() {
  $(".container-options").removeClass("open");
});

$("body").on("click", ".option", function() {
  var value = $(this).find("span").html();
  $(".selected").html(value);
  $("#sel").val(value);
  $(".container-options").toggleClass("open");  
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 25%;
}

.selected {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  min-width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.selected:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d7";
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
}

.container-options {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #3ea428;
  border-radius: 5px;  
  width: 155px;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.container-options .search {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.container-options .options {
  padding: 0.2em;
  max-height: 200px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container-options.open {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.search {
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

li>img {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="sel">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="selected">Select an option</div>
    <div class="container-options">
    <input type="text" id="search" class="search">
    <ul class="options"  id="fbody">      
      <li class="option"><span>Option 1</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 2</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 3</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 4</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 5</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 6</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 7</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 8</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 9</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 10</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 11</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 12</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 13</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 14</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 15</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 16</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 17</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 18</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 19</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 20</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 21</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 22</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 23</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 24</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 25</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 26</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 27</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 28</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 29</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 30</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 31</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 32</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>A</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>B</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>C</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>D</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>E</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>H</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>E</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>E</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>A</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Other</span></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Fantástico amigo eres grande... Amigo perdóname mi atrevimiento. Por favor que debo modificar el código jQuery para que este oculte las opciones si yo doy clic fuera de las opciones así como si fuera un `select option` normal

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta, intentalo.

Comment: se oculta pero si doy clic en el campo `input` que se encuentra dentro de las opciones se oculta :(

Comment: Ya edite otra vez.

Comment: Amigo que propiedad de los estilos css se necesita para que el contenido del `container-options` siempre este debajo del `selected` y no se vaya ir al costado o a los lados, que propiedad se necesita para que nunca pierda esa posición de estar siempre debajo del `selected`.

Comment: Creo que no necesitarias nada mas siempre y cuando esten en el mismo `container`.

Answer (score 0):

yo te recomendaria que usaras algun ***framework de codigo abierto*** en los que tienes estilos de todos los componentes que te ofrece html, mira las imagenes. En concreto este que te muestro lo puedes encontrar en la siguiente web:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeui/

Este framework funciona con javascript, jquery y es compatible con PHP y HTML5 que creo que son los lenguajes que quieres usar.
Tienes mas de 30 estilos diferentes gratuitos, y siempre los puedes retocar.
Existen mas soluciones similares en la web, o bien por medio de plantillas, o como en este caso que te ofrecen componentes completos, junto con su javascript-jquery con ejemplos para que puedas usarlos de inmediato.
Si necesitas mas ayuda, no dudes en decirmelo.

Un saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @SantiagoCelada tomaré en cuenta a futuro su respuesta, por ahora seguiré intentando con lo que he realizado, he llegado muy lejos como para dejarlo en un baúl de recuerdos :( saludos :)

Comment: Hola carla, como te decia, esto es de codigo abierto, y lo mas importante es la logica del programa que te viene incluida. El css, lo puedes modificar o poner el que estas usando pero si quieres un buscador en el select necesitas la logica del jquery. Si quieres un autocomplete necesitas la logica, etc... Lo dificil es hacerlo funcionar, puedes utilizar, la logica e implementar tu css. Mirate los componentes, el proyecto es la pagina, totalmente funcional que te he puesto arriba. Con todo el codigo que necesitas. Sustituye el css, o modifica el que te trae y ya lo tienes...;)

Comment: Te agradezco @SantiagoCeladaGonzalez el tiempo que has dedicado por responder pero no es lo que deseo, yo he invertido tiempo en mi trabajo, tengo todo funcionando solo me falta pequeños detalles.